# Package list file for update in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, apt, updates

If I execute update on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I do only updates, which are specified in some file . What is this file? (Sorry, if this topic is already duplicate)

Probably I will set my question a little bit much clearer. I search for a file, where all pathes are given for my updates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading apt-get man page answers you.

`man apt-get`

```
 update
           update is used to resynchronize the package index files from their
           sources. The indexes of available packages are fetched from the
           location(s) specified in /etc/apt/sources.list. For example, when
           using a Debian archive, this command retrieves and scans the
           Packages.gz files, so that information about new and updated
           packages is available. An update should always be performed before
           an upgrade or dist-upgrade. Please be aware that the overall
           progress meter will be incorrect as the size of the package files
           cannot be known in advance.
```

That is, `apt-get update` fetches the package lists from all repositories found in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory and updates the local database with information on the newest versions of packages and their dependencies.

Comment: exactly, /etc/apt/sources.list is what I search. thank you very much

Comment: @Guforu you are welcome, If you like my answer, just click the little grey ☑ under the "0" now turning it into  green. If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you really like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark and the little up-arrow http://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: I will accept your answer for sure. Just a little bit later, get a answer that I can't do it immediately